# How to convert byte to string in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters

I have a variable `b` whose value is `b'\xac\xed\x05sr\x00'`.

How can I convert it to `'aced05737200'`?

`s`, and `r` are converted to `73` and `72` respectively because their [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) are `73` and `72`.

`b.decode('utf-8')` gives me this error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position
>   0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex)-method

```
>>> b = b'\xac\xed\x05sr\x00'
>>> b.hex()
'aced05737200'
```

to get the wanted result, because it's not a problem with decoding or encoding. Your bytestring looks ok to produce a proper string object with hexadecimal numbers.